# How to extract contents of a large text file that appears to editors as only one line

Tags: text, sed, grep

I want to extract contents from large JSON files that appear to editors as one line (so I can't operate on a line basis), e.g.

```
{"license": 2, "file_name": "COCO_test2014_000000523573.jpg", "coco_url": "http://mscoco.org/images/523573", "height": 500, "width": 423, "date_captured": "2013-11-14 12:21:59", "id": 523573}, {"license . . .
```

For example, is there a way (sed, grep, ...?) I can search for the word `000000523573` and print the 100 characters preceding and 200 characters succeeding occurrences of the word?

Comment: Could you please include the code you've produced so far, the results you're getting, and an example of the results you're after? Check out the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) description and SO's "[How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guides on how to make this a great question.

Answer (score 2):

[**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the tool you want to use to parse JSON natively. If it's a structured format, don't treat it like random text.

```
$ jq . < input.json
{
  "license": 2,
  "file_name": "COCO_test2014_000000523573.jpg",
  "coco_url": "http://mscoco.org/images/523573",
  "height": 500,
  "width": 423,
  "date_captured": "2013-11-14 12:21:59",
  "id": 523573
}
$ jq .height < input.json
500
```

To search for a particular JSON record that contains a particular string in the `file_name` record, you might do something like this:

```
jq 'select(.file_name|contains("000000523573"))' < input.json
```

The notation here is ... longer to explain than makes sense for a single SO answer. Do have a look at the JQ query structure if you're interested in using this tool.

Comment: `+1` nice solution... please notice that jq has to be installed, as it's not there by default in any system

Comment: @FlashThunder - yes, absolutely. One of the reasons I provided the link. :) (I don't know what platform you're on, but I expect you should be able to find jq in your friendly neighbourhood package repository.)

Answer (score 0):

**data.txt:**

```
{"license": 2, "file_name": "COCO_test2014_000000523573.jpg", "coco_url": "http://mscoco.org/images/523573", "height": 500, "width": 423, "date_captured": "2013-11-14 12:21:59", "id": 523573}, {"license": 2, "file_name": "COCO_test2014_000000523574.jpg", "coco_url": "http://mscoco.org/images/523574", "height": 500, "width": 423, "date_captured": "2013-11-14 12:21:59", "id": 523574}
```

**command:**

```
cat data.txt | sed 's/\},\s{/}\n{/g' | grep "000000523573"
```

**output:**

```
{"license": 2, "file_name": "COCO_test2014_000000523573.jpg", "coco_url": "http://mscoco.org/images/523573", "height": 500, "width": 423, "date_captured": "2013-11-14 12:21:59", "id": 523573}
```

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated in [ghoti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404135/3266847), jq is definitely your best bet.

As for your exact question ("search for the word `000000523573` and print the 100 characters preceding and 200 characters succeeding"): you could use `grep -o` as follows:

```
grep -Eo '.{100}000000523573.{200}' infile
```

This has a few drawbacks:

- If `000000523573` occurs earlier than 100 characters from the beginning of the file or later than 200 characters from its end, it will be ignored.
- If the distance between two occurrences is less than 300 characters, the later occurrence will be ignored (overlapping occurrences are not accounted for by `grep -o`).

These can be alleviated *somewhat* by loosening the requirements to "print *up to* 100/200 characters before/after occurrences":

```
grep -Eo '.{,100}000000523573.{,200}' infile
```

But, again, the proper approach is to use jq. See also [this question about command line JSON parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools).